# How correctly to make OOP class with javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want to create javascript scripts using OOP and I've done one working class calculator, but I seem it's not done in correct way.

This is code of my class

```js
class CalculatorTable {
  constructor(
    aWeight1,
    aWeight2,
    aWeight3,
    sTotalPrice = "",
    sTotalGram = "",
    sWeight = "",
    sPrice = "",
    sPrice1 = "",
    sPrice2 = "",
    sPrice3 = "",
    sPriceForGram = "",
    sWeightToPrice = ""
  ) {
    // selectors
    this.sTotalPrice = sTotalPrice;
    this.sTotalGram = sTotalGram;
    this.sWeight = sWeight;
    this.sPrice = sPrice;
    this.sPrice1 = sPrice1;
    this.sPrice2 = sPrice2;
    this.sPrice3 = sPrice3;
    this.sPriceForGram = sPriceForGram;
    this.sWeightToPrice = sWeightToPrice;


    this.aWeight1 = aWeight1;
    this.aWeight2 = aWeight2;
    this.aWeight3 = aWeight3;

    this.price = 0;
    this.totalGram = 0;
    this.totalPrice = 0;

    this.changeWeight();
  }

  changeWeight() {
    var thisClass = this; //it's reference
    $(this.sWeight).on('change keyup paste', function(event) {
      thisClass.weight = $(this).val();
      // console.log("thisClass.weight="+thisClass.weight);
      thisClass.price1 = $(this).data(thisClass.sPrice1);
      thisClass.price2 = $(this).data(thisClass.sPrice2);
      thisClass.price3 = $(this).data(thisClass.sPrice3);
      thisClass.priceForGram = $(this).data(thisClass.sPriceForGram);
      thisClass.setPrice();
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td span.price').text(thisClass.price);
      // console.log("thisClass.price="+this.price);
      thisClass.setTotalGram();
      thisClass.setTotalPrice();

      // console.log(thisClass.price1+' '+thisClass.price2+' '+thisClass.price3+' ff'+thisClass.priceForGram);
    });
  }

  setPrice() {
    this.price = 0;
    if (this.weight >= this.aWeight1[0] && this.weight <= this.aWeight1[1]) {
      this.price = this.weight * this.price1;
    } else if (this.weight >= this.aWeight2[0] && this.weight <= this.aWeight2[1]) {
      this.price = this.weight * this.price2
    } else if (this.weight >= this.aWeight3[0] && this.weight <= this.aWeight3[1]) {
      this.price = this.weight * this.price3;
    }
  }

  setTotalGram() {
    var thisClass = this;
    thisClass.totalGram = 0;
    $(this.sWeight).each(function(index, el) {
      if ($(this).val().length !== 0) {
        thisClass.totalGram += parseFloat($(this).val());
      }
    });
    $(this.sTotalGram).text(this.totalGram);
  }

  setTotalPrice() {
    var thisClass = this;
    thisClass.totalPrice = 0;
    $(this.sPrice).each(function(index, el) {
      if ($(this).text().length !== 0) {
        thisClass.totalPrice += parseFloat($(this).text());
      }
    });
    $(this.sTotalPrice).text(this.totalPrice.toFixed(2));
  }


}

var calculator = new CalculatorTable(
  [1, 100], [101, 400], [401, 1000],
  'span.total-price',
  'span.total-gram',
  'input[name=weight]',
  'span.price',
  'price1',
  'price2',
  'price3',
  'price-for-gram',
  'td span.price'
);



console.log(calculator);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can I do code like this?

I interesting call this both functions

```
thisClass.setTotalGram();
thisClass.setTotalPrice();
```

is it right way I did it?

Comment: Share your code here itself, preferably as a working snippet using `<>`. Also, mention your specific concern about it.

Comment: Your code looks good. However please narrow it down to the error you get

Comment: I wanted put my code here and got the notice "your message have much code to please correct this", then I removed code. Ok, next time will try again to do this.

Code probably looks good, but I'm not sure about memory how it frees in javascript, If I called this methods thisClass.setTotalGram();
thisClass.setTotalPrice(); inside other methods and there I see object $(this) it will create a few times inside without free memory?

Comment: <quote>Your code looks good. However please narrow it down to the error you get</quote>
I'm not sure about this function setTotalGram and setTotalPrice, correctly I did always creating jquery object or not? Seems there will lack memory? 

for me this code also look good, and works it also good. Just want someone more experienced to correct me if there errors, its my first OOP in js